# Bitcoin logo in LaTeX?

Tags: bitcoin-logo

Is there a fairly simple way to include a standard-looking but not too elaborate "Bitcoin accepted here" logo in a LaTeX document?

Comment: Check this answer out from the Tex.StackExchange community: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/bitcoin-symbol-in-latex

Comment: @LucaMatteis: That seems to be for the Bitcoin currency symbol, not for the logo (e.g. the orange coin).

Comment: Asked and answered on Tex.SE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201597/bitcoin-accepted-here

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, check out this [answer on tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201597/how-to-create-a-bitcoin-accepted-here-button).

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\def\faBtc{\FA\symbol{"F15A}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary

{positioning}
\newcommand{\bitcoin}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,100}{
    \node [circle, fill=orange!90!white!\i, font=\large, inner sep=0.25ex, rotate=-15, text=white] 
    (symbol) at (-1.25,1/8+\i/4000) {\faBtc};}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\btc}{\ifmmode\text{\faBtc}\else\faBtc\fi}

\begin{document}
\SI{1000000}{\btc}
\bitcoin
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, the reason I posted here is that I thouoght someone here might know something that those who posted there do not know.  For example, maybe something like invoking one style file designed for the occasion and adding a single command to the document where the logo is to appear.